# Org agenda filter by headline depth

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Let's say I have a custom TODO tag called 'NEXT' and a file gtd.org which contains the following:

```
* Some category
** TODO Big project in category
*** NEXT Big step to completing project
**** NEXT Small step to completing big step
```

In my custom agenda view, I have a block listing everything with a NEXT tag. The problem is that this block lists the big step *and* the small step, whereas I only want to see the small step. That is, I'm looking for one of the following solutions, from most desirable to least desirable:

- Do not show a 'NEXT' headline if it has a child with 'NEXT' (probably resource        heavy)
- Sort the agenda block so that greater headline depth is on top
- Have different blocks for different headline depths

I **know** that org can detect headline depth, because when setting `org-agenda-prefix-format` its possible to add a number of spaces spaces to the prefix equaling the headline depth (using `%l`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having studied `org-mode` for a few weeks, I believe I can answer my own question.

- To hide headlines with children in `TODO` states, first put this in your `init.el` or equivalent:

  ```
  (setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
  ```

  The above will prevent a headline from entering a `DONE` state while a child is in a `TODO` state. `TODO` headlines with at least one child in a `TODO` state have the property `BLOCKED`. To prevent `BLOCKED` headlines from showing in agenda views, use

  ```
  (setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)
  ```
- Sorting the agenda block by headline depth is possible by creating a custom sorting strategy. The depth of a headline is given by the property `LEVEL`. As an example where `LEVEL` is used, org defaults to determining stuck projects by first tag searching for `"+LEVEL=2/-DONE"`. For more information, look up the syntax of tag searching.
- Distinct blocks for distinct headline depths can be achieved by using the `LEVEL` property, as described above.